# Deploying User Profile Application - My Sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, reporting-services

I need to use specific features available when deploying UPA. Hence I need to create a "my sites" site collection because I need to use the "Site feed" feature.

I need to know if deploying the my sites collection on the same web application but not using it will have any impact on the farm ?

I would also like to know what for the Reporting Site feature is used ? What does it imply ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not deploy MySites to the same Web Application due to the requirement of having self-service site creation enabled.

The Reporting feature is used for Usage Reporting of a particular Site Collection.

Comment: Self-service site creation will not be enabled.

Comment: SSSC is a check made when setting up MySites. It will fail to set up if you don't enable it.